# How to make play, pause button programmatically in Audio player in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am working on `AVAudioplayer` according to my project requirement.

I am creating play, pause, forward, backward programmatically.

I know how to create forward and backward button programmatically creation.

But I have no idea how to create play and pause buttons(means in audioplayer user click the play button automatically button will display pause button and if click the pause button automatically change the play button.).

how do I handle these two functionalities like play and pause buttons programmatically.

```
// Play Button creation


playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

playButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 380, 60, 60);

UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@“playButton.png"];

[playButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:playButton];


// Pause Button.


pauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

pauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(130, 380, 60, 60);

UIImage *pauseButton=[UIImage imageNamed:@“pauseButton.png”];

[pauseButton setImage:pauseButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseButtonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubView:pauseButton];
```

Comment: Create button and put its event ad [player play] and [player stop]

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you have to add one button on xib for play and pause purpose.
Now in xib set the background images of the button according to state config.

For play button- select state as default and then set the play image to button
For Pause button select state as Selected and then set the pause image to button

Now move to IBAction-

`-(IBAction)playPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender` and assign it to the button

Now

```
//playpause button pressed
-(void)playPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender
{   

    if([sender isSelected])//means pause
    {       
             //This will change the image of the button to play image
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;      
    }
    else//means play
    {    
    //This will change the image of the button to pause image
        [sender setSelected:YES];

          if(audioPlayer)
            {
                [audioPlayer release];
                audioPlayer=nil;
            }

            url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[tmsAppDeledate.songTitleArray objectAtIndex:tmsAppDeledate.selectedSongIndex]]];
            //path = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

            audioPlayer.delegate=self;
            [audioPlayer play];
            if(timer)
            {
                [timer invalidate];
                timer=nil;
            }

            [self startTimer];


        }           
            }       
}
```

In short handle the setSelected method of button for play and pause

Answer (score 0):

```
playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
    [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:playButton];




pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 100)];
[pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stevejobs.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:pauseButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Create a button in viewDidLoad() 
//UIButton *play = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      play = CGRectMake(100, 100, 160, 50);
-(void)PlayStop{

 if (playing==NO) {
// Init audio with playback capability

[play setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hmpause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 //hmpause.png is a image showing pause button
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:______ error:&err];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

audioPlayer.delegate=self;
[audioPlayer play];

playing=YES;
}
else if(playing==YES){
[play setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Audioplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 // 'Audioplay.png' is a image showing play button
[audioPlayer pause];

playing=NO;
```

}

}
Check the answer here 
[Play/Pause with the same button [AVAudioPlayer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635604/play-pause-with-the-same-button-avaudioplayer)

Comment: Don't forget to Set `playing =NO`  in viewdidload

Comment: thanks for your response.i have small doubt.firstly i want to create a Audioplayer view.i mean create UI.so as it is i wrote the code based on your answer?.I want to display play button by default.why because the avaudioplayer by default having play button na.so thats why?